# FCM HTTP Synchronous Requests

Tags: firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm not sure I am reading the docs correctly but in the Firebase Cloud Messaging [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server) discussing Firebase Cloud Messaging Server they mention the tradeoffs of using HTTP vs XMPP and I read the following in HTTP:

> HTTP: Synchronous. App servers send messages as HTTP POST requests and
>   wait for a response. This mechanism is synchronous and blocks the
>   sender from sending another message until the response is received.

Does this mean if I have multiple unrelated pushes that need to be sent to various devices, that I cannot send a second request until the first request is received? If I have three workers handling push notifications they would need to keep track of whether or not another one is waiting for a response from Firebase or am I misunderstanding the point?

Comment: did you encounter any issue with above statement. I am confused over the Synchronous part as well.

Comment: I have not implemented firebase yet, for some unrelated reasons but I was hoping to get an answer to this before implementing.

Comment: I wanted to do the same implementation. Any luck?

Comment: I have not run into any issues but can't say that the amount of push notifications I am sending would likely hit this edge case.